# Passing arguments for Dockerfiles using Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use parametrize my dockerfiles on build phase and use arguments in Docker-compose. For example in Docker compose I have defined one service called bpp as following:

```
bpp:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.bpp
    args:
      gp : 8080
  image: serv/bpp
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    - data
  links:
    - data
```

I'm trying to pass argument named gp to Dockerfile.bpp, where I'm using argument when starting a Python application, exposing a port etc.
For example in dockerfile.bpp in trying to expose port gp as following:

```
EXPOSE gp
```

However, when building docker file by command *docker-compose build* I get following error:
ERROR: Service 'bpp' failed to build: Invalid containerPort: gp

It seems that argument gp is not visible in dockerfile. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add `ARG gp` to your Dockerfile.

```
...
ARG gp

EXPOSE $gp
...
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Worth mentioning that this isn't going to expose the port when you're running it via compose though, you would need to add a `ports` instruction to your docker-compose.yml for that.

Answer (score 2):

First, [the syntax is](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build):

```
build:
  args:
    buildno: 1
    user: someuser

build:
  args:
    - buildno=1
    - user=someuser
```

So try with `gp: 8080`, not `gp : 8080`.

Second, make sure you are using [version 2 of the docker-compose.yml format](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2).

Third, try

```
EXPOSE $gp
```

Comment: I made a fix you proposed, but got following error: ERROR: Service 'bpp' failed to build: EXPOSE requires at least one argument

Comment: @lipponen did you try with $gb? I suppose it fails too without the $?

Comment: Yep, I had EXPOSE $gp in dockerfile

Comment: @lipponen Do you have version 2 in your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @lipponen Do you have `services:` before `bpp`?

Comment: Yes I have services: bpp:

Comment: @lipponen and it fails with or without the $? Would `EXPOSE ${gp}` work better?

Comment: Without $ I got error ERROR: Service 'bpp' failed to build: Invalid containerPort: gp and with $ and ${gp} I got ERROR: Service 'bpp' failed to build: EXPOSE requires at least one argument

Comment: @lipponen You arg is `gp`, not `gpp`: that would be `${gp}`

Comment: It was just typo in comments

Comment: @lipponen OK: what version of docker-compose and of docker are you using?

Comment: docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35 and docker Version:      1.11.1