# mvn clean install -PbuildDocker don't work

Tags: java, spring, microservices

It is my error info:

```
Step 9/10 : EXPOSE ${EXPOSED_PORT}
│[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
│[INFO] Reactor Summary:
│[INFO]
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-microservices ..................... SUCCESS [ 0.246 s]
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-admin-server ...................... FAILURE [ 10.753 s]
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-monitoring ........................ SKIPPED
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-customers-service ................. SKIPPED
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-vets-service ...................... SKIPPED
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-visits-service .................... SKIPPED
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-config-server ..................... SKIPPED
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-discovery-server .................. SKIPPED
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-api-gateway ....................... SKIPPED
│[INFO] spring-petclinic-tracing-server .................... SKIPPED
│[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
│[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
│[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
│[INFO] Total time: 11.951 s
│[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-11T10:30:27+08:00
│[INFO] Final Memory: 75M/651M
│[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
│[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default) on project spri
│ng-petclinic-admin-server: Exception caught: EXPOSE requires at least one argument -> [Help 1]
│[ERROR]
│[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
│[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
│[ERROR]
│[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following artic
│les:
│[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
│[ERROR]
│[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
│[ERROR] mvn -rf :spring-petclinic-admin-server
```

It seems like the expose require an argument. What it should be?

This is the dockerfile.

I have tried to set `EXPOSE_PORT` to `22` and `8899` which doesn't work.
This error info:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (default) on project spri
│ng-petclinic-admin-server: Exception caught: Request error: POST unix://localhost:80/build?buildargs=
│%7B%22ARTIFACT_NAME%22%3A%22spring-petclinic-admin-server-1.5.9%22%2C%22EXPOSED_PORT%22%3A%229090%22%
│7D&t=mszarlinski/spring-petclinic-admin-server: 500: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error -> [Help 1]
│[ERROR]
```

### Thanks!

This is the plugin apart of pom.xml about admin-server:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>buildDocker</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${docker.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: It looks like 'EXPOSE requires at least one argument'.

Comment: If your `EXPOSE_PORT` is an environment variable, it is probably not correctly set.

Comment: can you share a snippet of your pom.xml file where the plugin is defined, if it is okay to share it. also looking at this plugin, it seems you are using a very old version. latest is already 1.1.1 from here https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin and they also recommend to use the other plugin (https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) instead of this as it is currently in a frozen state except for bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) and set

```
<configuration>
    <container>
        <ports>
            <port>xxxx</port>
        </ports>
    </container>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime. You can specify whether the port listens on TCP or UDP, and the default is TCP if the protocol is not specified.

`EXPOSE <port> [<port>/<protocol>...]`

Example:
`EXPOSE 80/udp`

[Refer this.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

Also [see this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38058151/5674723)